# Programatically save Word Documents without dialog or progress popups

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

We have a complex VSTO Add-In for MS Word which automatically saves documents to a network drive. This save should happen completely transparently and in the background. We can't use Word's built-in auto save functionality here as it insists on saving things in OneDrive which isn't appropriate for us. And we can't use auto recover as that only saves to the local computer, not to a network location.

For some users working over a VPN the save can be a little bit slow and Word pops up a progress box. I've read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.save?view=word-pia), but it doesn't seem to offer any options to suppress the progress box. Our requirements are to automatically save the document every 30 seconds and seeing a popup box flash on the screen that frequently is distracting and frustrating.

Is there a way to programmatically and silently save a document in Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to always save to a local file, and copy it to the network drive in your code.

Comment: That's a great idea, but it also changes the document's file path to the temporary file path. If a user also manually saves, the changes go to that temporary file instead of the network location.

Comment: Yes, but that shouldn't matter as `Document.FullName` will point to the location, no matter what it is. Given, Word does not expose an event that fires after a document is saved, but you can always use a workaround like https://theofficecontext.com/2011/05/05/word-aftersave-event/

Comment: But SaveAs and SaveAs2 change Document.FulllName to point to the temporary file. And in any case, the original network file is locked while it is open in Word, so copying over top of it fails.

Comment: You can detect that the original file location was on a network drive and re-save to a new temporary location. Whenever the file is later saved, you can let it proceed saving to the temporary location, and then overwrite the original file on a network drive with the copy of the latest changes from a local temporary file.